# suppress solaris CC linker warning symbol XXX has differing sizes

Tags: solaris, cc

I got this linker error message:

```
ld: warning: symbol `_VersioN' has differing sizes:
        (file ./libsfc/libssl48.so value=0x16; file ./libsfc/libsipc.so value=0x15);
```

When I try to do link things:

```
CC -o foo foo.o bar.o ....
ld: warning: symbol `_VersioN' has differing sizes:
        (file ./libsfc/libssl48.so value=0x16; file ./libsfc/libsipc.so valu15);
[still generate foo binary]
```

I want to supress the warning message. if I've try to add -t option, but failed:

```
CC -t -o foo foo.o bar.o ...
CC: Warning: Option -t passed to ld, if ld is invoked, ignored otherwise
[won't generate foo binary]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your libssl48.so was built using a mapfile which specified a size for that particular variable.

If you want the Solaris Studio compiler to pass '-t' through to the linker, then you need to use   -Xlinker -t  rather than a bare  -t.

You need to post a bit more info to let people give you a more useful response.